# How to get values from the same index?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, stack

**I have a code here that can identify the indexes and bundle them together from the list (List). However, what I really want at the end is the list(TheListIWANT). Which puts all the values from the index 29, 11.. etc in the same array. Any clue how to proceed from here? **
from collections import defaultdict

```
List= [(29, 0.047325),
(29, 0.07054999999999999),
(29, 0.049889),
(29, 0.060329),
(29, 0.021406),
(29, 0.063948),
(29, 0.024941),
(11, 0.014238),
(11, 0.015177999999999999),
(8, 0.014424),
(8, 0.01583),
(0, 0.013855000000000001),
(0, 0.014922000000000001),
(0, 0.011966000000000001)]

ListIndex=[]
for i in range(len(List)):
    ListIndex.append(List[i][0])
    
    
TheListIWANT= [(29, [0.047325,0.07054999999999999, 0.049889, 0.060329, 0.021406, 0.063948, 0.024941 ]),(11, [0.015177999999999999,0.014238 ]),(8, [0.014424, 0.01583]),(0, [0.013855000000000001, 0.014922000000000001,
 0.011966000000000001])]

Indice = defaultdict(list)

for i, item in enumerate(ListIndex):
    Indice[item].append(i)

value=[]
for key, element in Indice.items():
    if len(element) > 0:
        KeyAndElement=key,element
        # value[item]
        value.append(KeyAndElement)

print(value)
 [(29, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), (11, [7, 8]), (8, [9, 10]), (0, [11, 12, 13])]
```

Comment: You should use a [dictionnary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) instead of a list

Answer (score 0):

The whole task can be done shorter but if you just want to appen to the given code you can use:

```
result = []
for k, vs in value:
    result.append((k, [List[v][1] for v in vs]))

print(result)
```